# Unable to install ruby using RVM on WSL 2 and Ubuntu

Tags: rvm, wsl-2

I have a windows 10 machine with WSL 2 and Ubuntu 20.x installed. I installed RVM on Ubuntu. RVM seems to be installed fine, but when I try and install a ruby `rvm install 3.1.2` I get the error `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/rvm/log/1658255479_ruby-3.1.2’: Permission denied` Anything special I should be doing on WSL 2 to make this work?

Comment: Do you have RVM installed in Windows or WSL?  Also, it may not matter, but what Linux distribution are you using in WSL?

Comment: Thanks for asking this @NotTheDr01ds I added more detail to the post.

Comment: Thanks Mark - Sorry for the continuing questions, but I'm working on trying to reproduce.  I see that there are multiple installation methods for RVM -- Since you are using Ubuntu, I'm assuming you used the PPA, right?  I'm trying that for now, but let me know if you used one of the other installation methods.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this exact error if I try `rvm install 3.1.2` without having added my user to the `rvm` group per the installation instructions.  Is it possible that you missed this step?

```
sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER
```

After adding the user, then exiting the shell/WSL and restarting, `rvm install 3.1.2` (almost) worked as expected.  It appears there's a slight bug where it asks for the `sudo` password on the same line as a previous `Updating system..` line, so it's easy to miss, but this is recoverable.

Comment: Great thanks. I originally istalled with `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm` but tried again on a fresh Ubutu app with instructions from https://rvm.io/rvm/install and that seemed to work without issue. I guess the disadvantage to installing that this is that you don't get auto-magic updates when you update Ubuntu?